# how to temporarily seal a narrow gap between baseboards and laminate floor?

Tags: baseboard

there is a very narrow (<1/8 in.) gap between the baseboards and the laminate floor in my bathroom, which has been letting in ants from the storage units on the other side of the wall.  is there any good way to seal the gap temporarily until my building is done being treated?  it's an apartment, so i can't do anything too permanent.  caulking?  some kind of tape?  any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You said it in your question: "caulking tape". I use the brand pictured but do not specifically endorse that brand. It is like string putty, you could gently press it into place and then remove it fairly easily. It does not cure like caulk, it remains a kinda stiff putty. I used it to seal a small roof transition crack while it was raining, then easily pulled it out and properly repaired the roof when the weather cleared up.

[image]

[image]